# Printing updated array board

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

This is my initial board. The first problem I'm having is that when the user enters the board size, it always prints the same 10 by 10 rather than what the user asked for. Secondly, I have a function below which is supposed to check each cell and convert the cells which match the condition to a whitespace or dash. I'm having trouble printing the board. Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10

int createBoard();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    createBoard();
}

int createBoard()
{
    char myArray[MAX][MAX];
    char letter[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int i,j,row,col;

    printf("Please enter your grid size: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    if(row < 10 && col < 10){
        for(i=0; i < MAX; i++){
            for(j=0; j < MAX; j++){
                myArray[i][j] = letter[rand()%3];
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i < MAX; i++){
            for(j=0; j < MAX; j++){
                printf("%c ", myArray[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
   }
   else{
        printf("Board is too big\n");
        createBoard();
   }
   int var;
   var = move(myArray);
}

//to check each cell
int newBoard(char myArray[MAX][MAX])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < MAX; i++){
        for(j=0; j< MAX; j++){
            if(myArray[i][j] == 'c' && myArray[i+1][j] == 'c'){
                myArray[i][j] == ' ';
                myArray[i+1][j] == ' ';
            }
            else{
                //no update
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a debugger. please use it.

Comment: Stop using SO to have your code written. And stop reposting the same code over and over again.

Comment: You haven't even learned the basic concepts of C. Read a tutorial. If you get stuck somewhere while reading it, by all means, ask _that_ question here. Your code has too many flaws to answer your question properly here. Maybe go to a programming board, where you can _discuss_ how to write your software.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st problem change your for loops

```
for(i=0; i < MAX; i++){
    for(j=0; j < MAX; j++){
     ...
   }
}
```

to use `row` and `col` variables

```
for(i=0; i < row; i++){
    for(j=0; j < col; j++){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers guys! First problem solved, any ideas on the printing an updated board?

Answer (score 0):

first problem solotion : 
because in your for loop you go through MAX
change it to :

```
for(i=0; i < row; i++){
    for(j=0; j < col; j++){
        myArray[i][j] = letter[rand()%3];
    }
}
```

second problem solution :
 first problem with check  function is that you should pass my Array by reference not by value 
  change it by adding'&' sign 
 second problem is you have to say  if(myArray[i][j] == 'c' && myArray[i+1][j] == 'c')
 this cause problem when i is equal to MAX-1 (last for step) and myArray[i+1][j] does not exist !!
 because the size of array is [MAX][MAX] and when i = MAX-1 , you size would be [MAX+1][MAX]

Comment: Sorry, i'm still a little confused about the second problem. So I have to change && to &? and then change change [i+1][j] to [MAX+1][MAX]?